# python script to read specific values from a csv file and insert them into a mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, database, csv, dictionary

I have created a very simple CSV file in which I only need certain specific values and insert them to my database. here's an example of the file:

```
eventkey, count, TotalDuration, Average
app_launch,147,11277,985
video_load,166,12815,940
evolving,2,0,0
playback,33,0,0
qp_library_fa,230,0,0
search_error,183,0,0
```

how can I insert only specific values from that file to a database using mysql and a phyton script?

For example;

I want to:

- insert the average of app_launch to a field in my database.
- insert the average of video_load to a field in my database.
- insert all the count values to each of their respective fields in the database.

so my database would have 8 fields:

(Average_app, Average_video,app_launch,video_load, evolving, playback,qp_library_fa,search_error ).

I started using a dictionary and works perfectly :)
here's my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
import csv
import MySQLdb
import os

dict= {}
infile= open('csv_err.log','r')
lines= infile.readlines()[1:-1]
for i in lines:
    eventKey, count, totalDuration, average   = [a.strip() for a in i.split(',')]
    dict.setdefault(eventKey, []).append([int(count), int(totalDuration), float(average)])
print dict
```

now my last step and scariest... how to access a specific value and assign it to my database? :S

Comment: Read all the values into a dictionary that uses the eventkey as the keys. Loop through the dictionary to calculate the averages. Then insert everything into the database in the appropriate fields. Which part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thank you barman
the average is already calculated, its the last value of each line.
I never heard of reading all values into a dictionary but i'm starting to look into it!
looks like my solution to my problem might there :)

Comment: Hello Barmar
i started using your idea of a dictionary but for some reason i cannot get it to save 3 values to each event key

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dict[eventKey] = [int(count), int(totalDuration), float(average)]`?